# Why does locationManager popup immediately disappear when used in another class?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I am using the `MapKit` to use `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to get the user's location. If I were to request for the user's location in ViewController's `viewDidLoad()` function, then the popup appears, asking the user for the user's input. Note: the two properties required to ask for the location (Location When In Use, and Location Always And When In Use) is added to Info.plist

That is,

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

      override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           locationManager = CLLocationManager()
           self.locationManager?.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
           self.locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
           self.locationManager?.delegate = self
           self.locationManager?.startUpdatingLocation()
      }
}
```

The code above works fine; when the program begins, it show a popup asking the user for their location.

However, If I was to create a new class `MapController` and put the same code inside that class, and create a new instance of `MapController` inside `viewDidLoad()`, then the popup immediately disappears when the program is run.

That is,

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {

     override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()
           let mapController = MapController(viewController: self)
           mapController.initialise()
     }
}

import MapKit
class MapController: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
      private let viewController: UIViewController
      private var locationManager: CLLocationManager

      required init(viewController: UIViewController) {
          self.viewController = viewController
          locationManager = CLLocationManager()
      }

      func initialise() {
           self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
           self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
           self.locationManager.delegate = self
           self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
      }
}
```

When the code above is run, the popup asking for the user's location immediately disappears.

My question being: why does the popup stay when the locationManager code is in the viewDidLoad(), but when the code is separated into another class, and called into viewDidLoad(), it immediately disappears. Why does this happen?

How can I separate the locationManager code into another class without the popup immediately disappearing?

Comment: You shouldn't unconditionally call `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`. You should always check `CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus` first and act accordingly. Moreover, don't make a class inherit from `NSObject` unless you have a reason to do so. In Swift, classes don't need to inherit from any base class.

Comment: @DávidPásztor If I don't inherit from NSObject, which class should I inherit from? MapController has to inherit `NSObject`, otherwise, removing it returns the error `MapController does not conform to protocol NSObjectProtocol`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a memory management issue. In `ViewController`, you create a local variable named `mapController` in `viewDidLoad`. At the end of `viewDidLoad`, that `MapController` instance goes out of scope and gets deallocated.

Instead of using a local variable in `viewDidLoad`, create a property.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
     var mapController: MapController!

     override func viewDidLoad() {
           super.viewDidLoad()

           mapController = MapController(viewController: self)
           mapController.initialise()
     }
}
```

But this now creates a reference cycle since `MapController` is keeping a strong reference to the view controller.

So you also need to change the `viewController` property of `MapController` to be `weak`.